# Pagination of thumbnails with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, pagination

my website http://www.rsphotographs.com is online since some days and I'd like to change the design slightly. However I don't know how so here is the "problem description" :-)

The website uses the jQuery plugin "FancyBox". If you look at a gallery on the website e.g. black & white you'll see that there are 15 thumbnails maximum per page. If there are more then there are more pages.

**Actual behavior**

1. Open gallery "black & white".
2. Click on last image on first page. The FancyBox plugin shows the larger image.
3. Click the right cursor key to cycle to the next image. FancyBox shows the first image of the first page again.

**Desired behavior**

Instead of showing the first image of the first page FancyBox shall show the next imge of the following page, i.e. the visitor may cycle through the complete gallery, not only pagewise.

I've seen that there are several pagination plugins for jQuery which could maybe accomplish this but I don't a clue how to split the thumbnails.

Is anyone able to help?

Cheers,
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is toe create 1 page with all you images and based on your pagination you online show the 15 first one.

With Fancybox you have a callback that gives you the position of your current image, based on that you show or hide the rest of your content. ($.fancybox.pos)

Example: You have 40 pictures in your galary. Than you show image 1 - 15 and you set 16 - 40 on display:none. When you are at picture 15 and the user clicks next, than you hide picture 1 - 15 and you show 16 - 30. Based on that you also change your pagination.

More info of the fancybox callbacks: http://fancybox.net/api

Comment: Thanks! The important hint for me is the first sentence of your posting. Thus I checked it as answer :-)